# How can i get the firefox add-on version number?

Tags: firefox-addon

My extension has package.json file containing install attribute.
Is there any way to get the add-on version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### AddonManager

You can get it from `AddonManager` module

```
Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm');

AddonManager.getAddonByID("YOUREXTENSIONID", function(addon) {
  var version = addon.version;
});
```

More info:
[AddonManager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager)
[Code Samples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager/Code_Samples)

**Note:** (from [AddonManager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager))

> The majority of the methods are asynchronous meaning that results are
>   delivered through callbacks passed to the method. The callbacks will
>   be called just once but that may be before or after the method
>   returns.

So the result may not be available immediately. I run `AddonManager.getAddonByID` at start-up and use the data later on, when needed.

### Addon-SDK

In addon SDK, you can get them from:

```
var self = require("sdk/self");
var version = self.version;
```

### Bootstrapped Addon

As pointed out bellow by [Noitidart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1828637/noitidart), certain addon data is available via `data.id`, `data.version`, `data.installPath`, `data.resourceURI` and `data.oldVersion` in the [Bootstrapped extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions)

```
function startup(data, reason) { }
function shutdown(data, reason) { }
function install(data, reason) { }
function uninstall(data, reason) { }
```

Comment: It's working one more question. will it work in content script

Comment: @Rajashekhar .. you can create the variable and insert it into content script but content script (ie page content scope) does not have access to Firefox Modules (browser scope) or else it would be a security problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are making a a bootstrap addon then the version is available via the `startup` function in the `aData` argument. What I do is I store the `aData` on startup into a global for future use.

```
var globalAData;
function startup(aReason, aData) {
    globalAData = aData;
    var version = aData.version;
}
```

From: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9025999#comment-1120821

This is the stuff that is contained in `aData`:

```
Key                 Value
id                  Bootstrap-Skeleton@jetpack
version             1.1
installPath         [xpconnect wrapped nsIFile]
resourceURI         [xpconnect wrapped nsIURI]
oldVersion          1.1
```

A note about the `oldVersion` key: Available only if there was a previously installed instance, could be same version like in this case. On reinstall and similar situations, the `version` and `oldVersion` are equal.

Comment: Thanks Noitidart ... I forgot to mention bootstrapped addons :)

Comment: @erosman Cool now your answer is very complete and pretty nice one :)

Answer (score 1):

For a non bootstrap (classic XUL Overlay), it is easier than I thought.

Effectively, you 'interrupt' the existing load function (main_load) fired by the `document load` event by introducing a new load function with the async `AddonManager.getAddonByID` call.  Wait for that to complete, before continuing to load your add-on using your previous function (just renamed, in this case to main_load_post, to indicate that we want to call this after the load).

In the `main.js` (corresponding to the `main.xul` file):

```
var myAddon = null;
window.addEventListener( 'load', main_load, false );
```

And elsewhere in same file (where ID is your addon ID):

```
// new main_load function to interrupt loading and assign to myAddon.
function main_load ( ) {
    AddonManager.getAddonByID( 'ID', function ( addon ) {
        myAddon = addon;
        main_load_post( );
    } );
}

// formerly 'main_load', renamed and called by the async callback.
function main_load_post ( ) {
    // main addon initialization: load prefs, setup pref observer, etc.
    // Note: your prefs.observe function will call something like main_load_prefs( ), etc
}

function main_load_prefs ( ) {
    // successful myAddon reference
    console.log( '***VERSION***: ' + myAddon.version );
}

// NOTE: Any myAddon reference must come from a call chain traced back to main_load_post( ).
// NOTE: You can't put myAddon references in global space outside function calls,
//       because the AddonManager callback may not have fired.
// console.log( '***VERSION***: ' + myAddon.version ); // This will always fail.

// NOTE: Nor can you call the function containing myAddon in a global context.
// main_load_prefs( );  // This will always fail.
```